# What is the different of dropbox and box.net?

Tags: dropbox

The first difference I mention is the free storage they give away to user:

1. dropbox.com 2Gb - 10Gb (after doing the referencing)
2. box.net only 1Gb

What else do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Desktop folder sync

- Not everyone can sync a (windows) folder with Box.net (yet):

> "We are currently rolling out Sync in waves to our Business and Enterprise customers"

- Dropbox sync tool works fine with windows folders
  2 Notes:

  - doesn't work through our corporate firewall.
  - The installation of the Dropbox sync tool doesn't ask for a location: the application gets installed inside your user profile somewhere. Which is too small for our corporate profile.

  But @ home it works just fine!

Comment: you can change the dropbox location after install. Though, I remember I can select the location while installation.

Comment: You can indeed change the location of the folder you want to sync, but AFAIK you cannot change the location of the service/application file: "dropboxsync.exe" or something. And that file is too big to store in my user profile which is limited by company policy.